# What is wrong with my code for phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql

I tried to make a database is phpmyadmin, but I keep getting an error.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0) NULL,
>     `Datum Verkocht` DATE NULL,
>     `Personeel` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
>     `Min' at line 9

That's for this code

```
CREATE TABLE `veilingen`.`Veilingen`(
  `Nr` INT(3) NOT NULL,
  `Artikel` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `Datum Geveild` DATE NULL,
  `Tel. Verkoper` INT(10) NULL,
  `Datum Ingeleverd` DATE NULL,
  `Kast`
SET
  (0) NULL,
  `Datum Verkocht` DATE NULL,
  `Personeel` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Minimum` DECIMAL NULL,
  `Koop Nu` DECIMAL(100) NULL,
  `Geveild Voor` DECIMAL(100) NULL,
  `Betaald` ENUM(0) NULL,
  `Cadeaubon` DECIMAL(100) NULL,
  `Versturen` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `Opmerkingen` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`Nr`(1))
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Sorry for the mess, I can't get the code span to work.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: How is this related to `C#` or `PHP` ?

Comment: (0) NULL - what is that?

Comment: ^ it's the error.

Comment: RTM http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- ;) Maybe I will ask like that: what do you think it is ? ;)

Comment: @nospor proverbial "did not read the manual" ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP did not read the manual on ENUM.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/abUVB) look, I haven't been programming for many years and start to pick it up again. In the image you can see the database I tried to make. I am a terrible programmer and I do not understand most of it. Please bear with me.

Answer (score 3):

Following is the right syntax for create table in php, you can edit this code according to your table name,column name and it's datatype.

CREATE TABLE  `employee` (
  `empId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `empName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `empDept` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`empId`)
)